# jQuery - handleCounter range setup with max value

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery handleCounter plugin with multiple inputs to adjust the container blocks.

I have 3 input fields with minimum and maximum number to be entered as 600 always. If I adjust any number, other fields should share the remaining / get reduced.

By default I have set the 200 for each field.

Currently, if I adjust any of these 3 inputs, other inputs are sharing the remaining value.

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/qrt9hLmk/2/)

What I am expecting here is:

**In this case, maximum value is 600**

[image]

### **What I need is**:

> 1. If I enter value in first field, only second field's input value should get adjusted (until total value did not cross 600, if crosses
>    it should use third filed's value)
> 2. If I enter value in second field, only third filed's input value should get adjusted (until total value did not cross 600, if crosses
>    it should use first filed's value) In below scenario, 2nd input value
>    changed from 100 to 180. So 3rd filed input value has taken remaining
>    value which is 120 (300 + 180 = 480, **reamining 120**)
> 3. In the same way, If I adjust the value from bottom it should be reversed. Eg: Enter the value in 3rd input field, 2nd input field's
>    value gets adjusted. 2nd input value enters, first input value should
>    altered.

[image]

[image]

```js
/* Plugin starts */
;(function () {
'use strict';
var maxVal = 600;
var inputLength = $('.rpHandleCounter input').length - 1
$.fn.handleCounter = function (options) {
  var $input,
      $btnMinus,
      $btnPlugs,
      minimum,
      maximize,
      writable,
      onChange,
      onMinimum,
      onMaximize;
  var $handleCounter = this
  $btnMinus = $handleCounter.find('.counter-minus')
  $input = $handleCounter.find('input')
  $btnPlugs = $handleCounter.find('.counter-plus')
  var defaultOpts = {
    writable: true,
    minimum: 1,
    maximize: null,
    onChange: function(){},
    onMinimum: function(){},
    onMaximize: function(){}
  }
  var settings = $.extend({}, defaultOpts, options)
  minimum = settings.minimum
  maximize = settings.maximize
  writable = settings.writable
  onChange = settings.onChange
  onMinimum = settings.onMinimum
  onMaximize = settings.onMaximize
  if (!$.isNumeric(minimum)) {
    minimum = defaultOpts.minimum
  }
  if (!$.isNumeric(maximize)) {
    maximize = defaultOpts.maximize
  }
  var inputVal = $input.val()
  if (isNaN(parseInt(inputVal))) {
    inputVal = $input.val(0).val()
  }
  if (!writable) {
    $input.prop('disabled', true)
  }

  changeVal(inputVal)
  $input.val(inputVal)
  $btnMinus.click(function () {
    var num = parseInt($input.val())
    if (num > minimum) {
      $input.val(num - 1)
      changeVal(num - 1)
      if($('.div-split').length > 0) {
        splitDiv($handleCounter,num-1)
      }
    }
  })
  $btnPlugs.click(function () {
    var num = parseInt($input.val())
    if (maximize==null||num < maximize) {
      $input.val(num + 1)
      changeVal(num + 1)
      if($('.div-split').length > 0) {
        splitDiv($handleCounter,num+1)
      }
    }
  })
  var keyUpTime
  $input.keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(keyUpTime)
    keyUpTime = setTimeout(function() {
      var num = $input.val()
      if (num == ''){
        num = minimum
        $input.val(minimum)
      }
      var reg = new RegExp("^[\\d]*$")
      if (isNaN(parseInt(num)) || !reg.test(num)) {
        $input.val($input.data('num'))
        changeVal($input.data('num'))
      } else if (num < minimum) {
        $input.val(minimum)
        changeVal(minimum)
      }else if (maximize!=null&&num > maximize) {
        $input.val(maximize)
        changeVal(maximize)
      } else {
        changeVal(num)
      }
      if($('.div-split').length > 0) {
        splitDiv($handleCounter,num)
      }

    },300)
  })
  $input.focus(function () {
    var num = $input.val()
    if (num == 0) $input.select()
  })

  function changeVal(num) {
    $input.data('num', num)
    $btnMinus.prop('disabled', false)
    $btnPlugs.prop('disabled', false)
    if (num <= minimum) {
      $btnMinus.prop('disabled', true)
      onMinimum.call(this, num)
    } else if (maximize!=null&&num >= maximize) {
      $btnPlugs.prop('disabled', true)
      onMaximize.call(this, num)
    }
    onChange.call(this, num)
  }

  function splitDiv($handleCounter,num) {
    if(maxVal > num){
      var remainigVal = Math.floor((maxVal - num) / inputLength)
      jQuery('td.cls-com').attr('width', remainigVal);
      jQuery('td.'+$handleCounter[0].attributes[2].value).attr('width', num);
      $('.rpHandleCounter input').val(remainigVal)
      $($handleCounter.selector+' input').val(num) 
      var cnt = 0
      $('.rpHandleCounter input').each(function(){
        cnt = cnt + Number($(this).val())
      })
      var remaingCnt = Number(maxVal-cnt);
      if($($handleCounter.selector).next()[0].attributes[0].value !=="tableData") {
        $($handleCounter.selector).next().find('input').val(remainigVal+remaingCnt)
        jQuery('td.'+$($handleCounter.selector).next()[0].attributes[2].value).attr('width', remainigVal+remaingCnt);
      } else {
        $($handleCounter.selector).prev().find('input').val(remainigVal+remaingCnt)
        jQuery('td.'+$($handleCounter.selector).prev()[0].attributes[2].value).attr('width', remainigVal+remaingCnt);
      }
    } else {
      jQuery('td.cls-com').attr('width', 0);
      jQuery('td.'+$handleCounter[0].attributes[2].value).attr('width', num);
      $('.rpHandleCounter input').val(0)
      $($handleCounter.selector+' input').val(num) 
    }

  }
  return $handleCounter
};
})(jQuery);
/* Plugin ends */
//var maxVal = 600;
//var inputLength = $('.rpHandleCounter input').length - 1
$('.rpHandleCounter').each(function(){
var tdCls = $(this).attr('data-class');
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('#'+id).handleCounter({
  minimum: 0,
  maximize: 600,
  onChange:function(num){
  },
  onMinimum:function(num){
    console.log('onMinimum 1');
  },
  onMaximize:function(num){
    console.log('onMaximize 1');
  }
});

})
```

```css
.handle-counter { overflow: hidden;margin-top:10px; }

.handle-counter .counter-minus,  .handle-counter .counter-plus,  .handle-counter input {
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

.handle-counter .counter-minus,  .handle-counter .counter-plus { text-align: center; }

.handle-counter input {
width: 50px;
border-width: 1px;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
height:26px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn {
padding: 6px 12px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
color: #fff;
cursor:pointer;
}

.btn:disabled, .btn:disabled:hover {
background-color: darkgrey;
cursor: not-allowed;
}

.btn-primary { background-color: #009dda; }

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus { background-color: #0486b9; }

body{font-family:Verdana, Arial;font-size:13px;}
.tableData{margin-top:20px;}
.tableData table, .tableData td{border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse;}
.tableData td{padding:0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-split">
  <div class="handle-counter rpHandleCounter" id="counter1" data-class="clas-1">
    <button class="counter-minus btn btn-primary">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="200">
    <button class="counter-plus btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="handle-counter rpHandleCounter" id="counter2" data-class="clas-2">
    <button class="counter-minus btn btn-primary">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="200">
    <button class="counter-plus btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="handle-counter rpHandleCounter" id="counter3" data-class="clas-3">
    <button class="counter-minus btn btn-primary">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="200">
    <button class="counter-plus btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tableData">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="col-1 clas-1 cls-com" width="200">
          Column 1
          <div id="col1Value"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-2 clas-2 cls-com" width="150">
          Column 2
          <div id="col2Value"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-3 clas-3 cls-com" width="250">
          Column 3
          <div id="col3Value"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question here -  What is the expected output ?

Comment: If I adjust the value in first field, only second field value should get altered or by adjusting 2nd field value only 3rd field value should get adjusted (but maximum should not cross 600 - by all three fields total)... Same way from bottom, 3rd field value adjusted, above (2nd field) value gets adjusted... Hope it is clear now

Comment: Generally if there's no question mark (`?`) in your question, you haven't narrowed it down enough. There's a lot of info in this question, is all of it necessary to the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DBS, thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the same. Can you please check

Comment: Requirement specifications 2 & 3 contradict each other. "If I enter value in second field, only third filed's input value should get adjusted". "In the same way, If I adjust the value from bottom it should be reversed. 2nd input value enters, first input value should altered"